# Let $X$ be a space equipped with topology $\mathcal{T}$. Determine the final topology on a set $Y$ induced by the constant maps $g:X \to Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a space equipped with topology $\mathcal{T}$. Determine the final topology on a set $Y$ induced by the constant maps $g:X \to Y$.

If $g(x)=y_0$ for every $x \in X$ and the final topology is defined as $\mathcal{T}’ = \{U \subset Y : f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T} \}$, then for any $f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T}$ I have $f^{-1}(U) = \{x \in X \mid y_0 \in U \}$ and this set has to be in the topology on $X$. It seems that this is should be the discrete topology, but how to prove this from here?

Comment: What do you mean by "final topology"? Is it the same as "finest"? (That is, the largest possible topology on $Y$.)

Comment: Here’s the definition https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the discrete topology is the answer. In fact, using the definition in the link, we can prove this without any heavy work or working with preimages.

1. First note that if $g$ is continuous w.r.t. $(Y, \mathcal{T}_{\text{discrete}})$, then the answer is indeed "the discrete topology" since the discrete topology is finer than any topology on $Y$.
2. $g$ is indeed continuous w.r.t. $(Y, \mathcal{T}_{\text{discrete}})$ because constant maps are **always** continuous!

---

**Note.** Here I have taken the definition to be:

> The finest topology on $Y$ which makes $g$ continuous.

The description you've given is not what I've used (that description explicitly describes the topology). However, we can do it using that as well.

As you've written, we have $$\mathcal{T}’ = \{U \subset Y : f^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{T}\}.$$
We now wish to show that every set $U \subset Y$ is open. Equivalently, we wish to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open (in $X$) for every subset $U \subset Y$.
But this is simple, because $f^{-1}(U)$ is either $X$ or $\varnothing$, depending on whether $U$ contains the image of $g$ or not. By definition of topology, we must have $\varnothing, X \in \mathcal{T}$.